# Is it possible to (deep) copy back all of the dynamic allocated memory in device (in array of pointers manner)?

Tags: cuda, dynamic-memory-allocation

Here is something like what I want to do:

```
__global__ void malloc(int **d_array) 
{ 
    int* ptr = (int*)malloc(x);
    // x is different within each thread and cannot be determined
    // compile time..

    // then fill that space with something and put it in the d_array

    d_array[threadIdx.x] = ptr;
} 
void main() 
{ 
    int **d_array; int *h_array;
    int blockSize = 32;
    cudaThreadSetLimit(cudaLimitMallocHeapSize, somethingBigEnough);
    cudaMalloc(d_array, sizeof(int *) * 32); 

    mallocTest<<<1, blockSize>>>(d_array); 
    cudaThreadSynchronize();

    //here is what I want:
    h_array = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * maxSize);
    cudaDeepMemcpy(h_array, d_array, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
}
```

I am looking for something like a "deepMemcpy" in cuda. If it is not supported, what ways I can use to copy generated runtime data back to the host?

Comment: pointers allocated by device malloc cannot be used in a cuda runtime API memcpy function.  The only method will be to do a memory-to-memory copy using a kernel (to memory allocated by `cudaMalloc` or the like), if you have data in a device malloc'ed region that you want to move to the host.

Comment: Strange things come from people who don't care.. Why a downvote to a question like this!? SO community has changed a lot for sure..

Comment: @RobertCrovella : Thanks for making it clear. Is it still not possible to initiate a `cudaMemcpy` inside a kernel (using dynamic parallelism feature) and pass the dynamic allocated memory?

Comment: Memcpy has been supported in CUDA kernels *forever*. Everything in this question could be answered by just reading some documentation

Comment: @talonmies: I know that Memcpy inside kernels is supported. The important part of the question was the possibilty of passing dynamic allocated memory to it. And FYI, I have read all of the cuda programming guide version 7.0 twice and I didn't get any answer to my question. Thanks for helping

Comment: In kernel `memcpy` can move data from device memory to device memory, regardless of how that memory was allocated.  `cudaMemcpy` called from a kernel is still part of the cuda runtime API, and it has the [additional restriction](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#api-reference) that *only* device-to-device memcpys are supported.  Niether of these methods can target host memory.

Comment: I guess you completely missed [this section](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#dynamic-global-memory-allocation-and-operations) then? Which explcitly says malloc, free, memset and memcpy are supported for operating on runtime heap memory within a kernel and what the restrictions are on their use.

Comment: You are right. Yes it is completely explained. I think the good way is to implement the second kernel to gather dynamic data into a buffer and then copy back that buffer.

Comment: If we leave aside the impossibility of using heap memory for this for a moment, in your kernel pseudo code you say "x is different within each thread and cannot be determined at compile time", and you show the proposed `cudaDeepMemcpy` using a flat, contiguous memory allocation for the destination on the host. How could that work? If each thread's device array is a different length, how would a copy function know the length of the sub array so as to copy the correct amount of data? At the very minimum you would need a second array containing the length of each sub-array.

Comment: I think the idea of constructing a second array, is easy to implement. We can provide `cudaDeepMemcpy` from an array of pointers to a host flat array or maybe an array of pointers like it's device version. For the flat version, a reduction of "length"s of sub-array to determine total size is needed for allocation. Then `cudaDeemMemcpy` is somehow a wrapper. And BTW, I just read your "about me" and that explains the downvote and to be honest, you care a lot. sorry for the first comment